# Can't import Vue into Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I haven't used Laravel in ages and I'd like to import Vue into Laravel, because I know more about Vue. I've [created a new Laravel Project](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation), [Installed Vue](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-set-up-and-use-vue-in-your-laravel-8-app-2dd0f174e1f8) [(Link 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ6PD_jBtU0) and still I'm seeing just a [White screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvems.jpg). Code is posted below. I'm probably just missing a thing or two but can't seem to find out what it is.

To run the project I'm running `php artisan serve`.

welcome.blade.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>IPMEDTH</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <example-component></example-component>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> also tried this -->
</body>
```

app.js code (while posting this I found out it doesn't reach this code, but why not?)
(see 'White screen'/Imgur link for folder structure)

```
alert("Hello World!"); // to test if js code is reached

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;files(key).default))

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

exampleComponent.vue code

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm an example component.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: First, double check for typos: you are loading `ExampleComponent.vue` but you may have [incorrectly named if standard naming convention followed] `exampleComponent.vue` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tpojka, however the ExampleComponent comes installed with installing Vue into Laravel, meaning it’s default. There was no typo unfortunately, do you have any other suggestions?